# Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failing with exception "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running my application on Elastic Beanstalk on a 64bit Amazon Linux distro.

Proxy server is NGINX & Node version 6.11.1

Deployments has been a breeze over the last several months & started failing out of the blues since last evening. No changes have been made to the beanstalk config.

Log trace from eb-activity.log

```
 [2018-01-30T17:35:10.892Z] INFO  [3620]  - [Application update
 app-a958-180130_183239@128/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh]
 : **Activity has unexpected exception, because: invalid byte sequence in
 UTF-8 (ArgumentError)  at**
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:272:in `gsub'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:272:in `format_result'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:151:in `timeout_exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:123:in `block in create'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `instance_eval'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `create'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/hook-directory-executor.rb:29:in
 `block in run!'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/hook-directory-executor.rb:27:in
 `each'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/hook-directory-executor.rb:27:in
 `run!'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:211:in
 `block (3 levels) in exec_stage'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `call'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:140:in `timeout_exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:123:in `block in create'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `instance_eval'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `create'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:206:in
 `block (2 levels) in exec_stage'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in
 `each'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in
 `each_with_index'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in
 `block in exec_stage'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `call'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:140:in `timeout_exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:123:in `block in create'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `instance_eval'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `create'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:201:in
 `exec_stage'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:148:in
 `execute!'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:77:in
 `block (3 levels) in execute!'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `call'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:195:in `exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:140:in `timeout_exec'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:123:in `block in create'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `instance_eval'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:122:in `create'   from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:74:in
 `block (2 levels) in execute!'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:144:in
 `execute_command'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:70:in
 `block in execute!'    from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/healthd_reporter.rb:50:in
 `log'  from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:69:in
 `execute!'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.10/bin/command-processor:45:in
 `<top (required)>'     from
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in
 `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue in eb-activity log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause & workaround posted here - https://commscentral.net/tech/?post=65

Comment: Has there been any news of this?

Comment: Or do you remember how to access ebnode.py? Is it through the EB CLI?

Comment: Yes through the CLI. Path for file - /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py